# Problem: removing duplicates inside an arraylist of strings in alphabetical order

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Here is my function that removes duplicates from an arraylist (sorted in alphabetical order):

```
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<String> array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (i + 1 < array.size()) {
            if (array.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase((array.get(i + 1)))) {
                array.remove(i + 1);
                i=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow there's still some duplicate, I've look other method to remove duplicate in an arraylist and they're exactly like mine. So now I'm tripping real hard. If you can help find the solution to my problem, it would be very much appreciated. Btw here is a sample of what is the output when I print my arraylist after clling on it the function removeDuplicate(array):

A
ABILITY
ACCORDED
ACQUIRED
ADULT
AFTER
AGAIN
AGAINST
AGE
AGE
ALBERT
ALIENATED
ALL
ALMOST

Comment: If possible, consider changing the method to return a new List<String> which has the duplicates removed, and the input parameter is unchanged.  (The caller of the method can re-assign the result if needed.)  If that approach is possible, then Streams with distinct could be used.

Comment: Why not just assign to another list and not add an element if it already exists? In this world of Collections and lambdas it seems odd to iterate through a list like an array. 

You can try this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: I just used your function and it works perfectly, what seems to be the issue? The sample input results in this output: [A, ABILITY, ACCORDED, ACQUIRED, ADULT, AFTER, AGAIN, AGAINST, AGE, ALBERT, ALIENATED, ALL, ALMOST]

Comment: @Rubydesic, nice catch :)  The only duplicate entry `AGE` is successfully removed by OP's snippet, however, resetting index to 0 seems to be redundant for a _sorted_ list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing method should use loop starting from the end of the list:

```java
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<String> array) {
    for (int i = array.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (array.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase((array.get(i - 1)))) {
            array.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In case the input list is *partly* sorted, a `Set` may be used to track duplicates:

```java
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList<String> array) {    
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (!set.add(array.get(i).toUpperCase())) {
            array.remove(i--); // important to decrement the index!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a list while iterating through it usually bites back.

Try this

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicate(ArrayList<String> array) {
  return array.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: OP wants to make a case-insensitive comparison